# Javascript JSON Read Objects Values?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this from my server return:

```
reminder:"["15", {"reminder_server": Balancer #5, "reminder_day": 16}]"
```

And I would like to read values `reminder_server` and `reminder_day` and my try is this:

```
if (typeof data.reminder !== 'undefined' && data.reminder.length > 0) {
    var remind = data.reminder;

    for( var k = 0; k < remind.length; k+=2 ) {
        var id = remind[k];
        var reminder = remind[k+2];

        /* ADD - reminder */
        console.log(reminder.reminder_server);

        /* INCREMENT - counter */
        k++;
    }
}
```

But I always get this in `console.log`:

> 28 undefined

Or

> ]

So I don't know what is causing this, on server side i run with nodejs this:

```
res.json(data);
```

So that string is converted to JSON object and send to client.

Comment: "reminder_server" with the value of "Balancer #5" should be enclose in quotes as it needs to be a string.

Comment: Why remind [k+2] and not remind [k+1] ?!

Comment: You are rigtht Matt i added "Balancer #5" into quotes and [k+1] as Hai Alaluf point me and now it works..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reminder` is a string of JSON. It isn't a JavaScript array.

You have to parse it with `JSON.parse` first.